# Select drawn figure within panel box

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I am working on an 'use-case-diagram-form' where an user can select an element and a modus

[image]

Just a simple form. It al works fine, made a class for each actor element and each use-case element. Both are added in a list after beeing created.

But somehow I just can't figure out how to select a created element and after do something with it.

classes i made:

```
    class Actor
{
    private static int _id;
    private Panel _panel;
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int X { get; private set; }
    public int Y { get; private set; }


    public Actor(Panel panel, string name, int x, int y)
    {
        _id++;
        _panel = panel;
        Name = name;
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public void DrawActor()
    {
        // draw Actor
        var graphics = _panel.CreateGraphics();
        var pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
        graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, X - 10, Y - 30, 20, 20);
        graphics.DrawLine(pen, X, Y - 10, X, Y + 20);
        graphics.DrawLine(pen, X - 15, Y, X + 15, Y);
        graphics.DrawLine(pen, X, Y + 20, X - 15, Y + 35);
        graphics.DrawLine(pen, X, Y + 20, X + 15, Y + 35);


        // rectangle around actor
        graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, (X - 20), (Y - 30), 40, 80);



        // setup font
        var stringFont = new Font("Arial", 10);

        // measure string
        var textWith = graphics.MeasureString(Name, stringFont).Width;


        // label
        var label = new Label();
        var actorText = (_id < 10 ? "0" : "") + _id.ToString() + "-" + Name;
        label.Text = actorText;
        label.Location = new Point(X - (Convert.ToInt32(textWith)/2), Y + 40);
        label.AutoSize = true;
        label.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        _panel.Controls.Add(label);

    }
    class UseCase
{
    private static int _id;
    private Panel _panel;
    private string _name;
    private int _x;
    private int _y;

    public UseCase(Panel panel, string name, int x, int y)
    {
        _id++;
        _panel = panel;
        _name = name;
        _x = x;
        _y = y;
    }

    public void DrawUseCase()
    {
        var graphics = _panel.CreateGraphics();
        var pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
        graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, _x , _y , 120, 50);

        // setup font
        var stringFont = new Font("Arial", 10);

        // measure string
        var textWith = graphics.MeasureString(_name, stringFont).Width;

        // label
        var label = new Label();
        var useCaseText = (_id < 10 ? "0" : "") + _id.ToString() + "-" + _name;
        label.Text = useCaseText;
        label.Location = new Point(_x - (Convert.ToInt32(textWith) / 2) + 60, _y + 20);
        label.AutoSize = true;
        label.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        _panel.Controls.Add(label);

    }
}
```

Github repository:
https://github.com/JimVercoelen/use-case-helper

Thanks

Comment: A diagram designer is something that is quite complex to design. There are a number of problems to solve, and selection is one of the easier ones.
Consider taking a look at this excellent series on developing a diagram designer. It uses WPF http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has several issues, all of which will go away once you learn how to draw **properly** in winforms!

There are many posts describing it but what you need to understand that you really have these two options:

- Draw **onto** the surface of the control. This is what you do, but you do it all wrong.
- Draw **into** a `Bitmap` which is displayed in the control, like the `Picturbox`'s `Image` or a `Panel`'s `BackgroundImage`.

Option two is best for graphics that slowly add up and won't need to be corrected all the time.

Option one is best for interactive graphics, where the user will move things around a lot or change  or delete them.

You can also mix the options by caching drawn graphics in a `Bitmap` when they get too numerous.

Since you started with drawing onto the surface let's see how you should do it correctly:

**The Golden Rule: All drawing needs to be done in the control's `Paint` event or be triggered from there always using only the `Paint` event's `e.Graphics` object!**

Instead you have created a `Graphics` object by using `control.CreateGraphics`. This is almost always **wrong**.

One consequence of the above rule is that the `Paint` event needs to be able to draw **all** objects the user has created so far.  So you will need to have class level lists to hold the necessary data: `List<ActorClass>` and `List<UseCaseClass>`. Then it can do maybe a

```
foreach(ActorClass actor in ActorList) actor.drawActor(e.Graphics)
```

etc.

Yes this fully repainting everything looks like a waste but it won't be a problem until you need to draw several hundreds of object.

**But if you don't do it this way, nothing you draw persists.**

**Test** it by running your present code and doing a `Minimize/Maximize` sequence. Poof, all drawings are gone..

Now back to your original question: How to select an e.g. Actor?

This really gets simple as you can can iterate over the `ActorList` in the `MouseClick` event (do not use the `Click` event, as it lacks the necessary parameters):

```
foreach (ActorClass actor in ActorList) 
   if (actor.rectangle.Contains e.Location)
      {
         // do stuff
         break;
      }
```

This is a simple implementation; you may want to refine it for the case of overlapping objects..

Now you could do things like maybe change the color of the rectangle or add a reference to the object in a `currentActor` variable.

Whenever you have made any changes to your lists of things to draw, like adding or deleting a object or moving it or changing any (visible) properties you should trigger an update via the `Paint` event by calling `Invalidate`.

Btw: You asked about a `PictureBox` in the title but use only a `Panel` in the code. Using a `PictureBox`is recommended as it is **doublebuffered** and also combines **two** Bitmaps to let you use both a caching `Image` and a `BackgroundImage` with maybe a nice paper..

As far as I can see your code so far lacks the necessary classes. When you write them add a Draw routine and either a reference to the `Label` you add or simply use `DrawString` to draw the text yourself..

**Update:**

After looking at your project, here a the **minimal** changes to make the drawing work:

```
// private Graphics graphics; // delete!!
```

**Never** try to cache a `Graphics` object!

```
private void pl_Diagram_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
    DrawElements(e.Graphics);                 // pass out the 'good' object
    //graphics = pl_Diagram.CreateGraphics(); // delete! 
}
```

The same; pass the real `Graphics` object into the drawing routine instead!

```
    // actor
    if (rb_Actor.Checked)
    {
        if (e.X <= 150)
        {
            var actor = new Actor(name, e.X, e.Y);
            _actors.Add(actor);
            pl_Diagram.Invalidate();  // trigger the paint event
            //DrawElements();
        }
    }

    // use case
    if (rb_Use_Cases.Checked)
    {
        var useCase = new UseCase(name, e.X, e.Y);
        _useCases.Add(useCase);
        pl_Diagram.Invalidate();  // trigger the paint event
        //DrawElements();
    }
```

Instead of calling the routine directly we trigger the `Paint` event, which then can pass a good `Graphics` object to it.

```
public void DrawElements(Graphics graphics)
{
    foreach (var actor in _actors)
    {
        DrawActor(graphics, actor);
    }

    foreach (var useCase in _useCases)
    {
        DrawUseCase(graphics, useCase);
    }
}
```

We receive the Graphics object and pass it on..

```
    private void DrawActor(Graphics  graphics, Actor actor)
```

and

```
    graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, (useCase.X - 60), (useCase.Y - 30), 120, 60);
```

After these few changes the drawing persists.

Replacing the `Panel` by a `Picturebox` is still recommended to avoid flicker during the redraw. (Or replace by a double-buffered Panel subclass..)

Comment: Hey @TaW, thanks for response! Updated git repository, modified the classes en trown the drawing within the mainclass. But Wat I could not figure out is how the paint event works with the e.graphics because that one wasn't working. Have it now as graphics = panel Name.createGraphics, which works but drawings disapear after resizing

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the comment; if it still applies I'll have a look into it later; using the `e.Graphics` object in the `Paint` event (and triggering it with `Invalidate()` ) is crucial to let the system do the necessary re-painting both after some events like minimizing and also to make a `DrawToBitmap` work, which you'll need to save the drawing..

Comment: I have update the anwer with the necessary code changes. Do plan for growth now and make a list of the next features you want to add!. Move, delete, save data, save graphics come to mind..